# PHP Laravel REST api double reverse relation

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building a REST API using Laravel. My database has a table called container. Container has foreign relation to another table called Shop. Finally there is a Image table which has foreign key to the Shop table. 
I want to have an endpoint for my containers which will return the container data including the data from Shop that it is assigned to as well as all the images that are assigned to the shop.

this is my Container resource :

```
class Container extends JsonResource
{

    public function toArray($request)
    {

        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'shop_id' => $this->shop_id,
            'shop' => (new ShopResource($this->whenLoaded('shop')))
        ];
    }
}
```

this is my Shop Resource:

```
class Shop extends JsonResource
{

    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```

and here is my Container controller:

```
class ContainerController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return ContainerResource::collection(Container::with('shop')->get());
    }
}
```

Basicaly in Django all i would have to do would be to assign related_name to the Image model, (eg. related_name="images")   and i would get all the images related to the shop model in my database by using eg. Shop.objects.first().images which would be taken in account in the Containers Serializer. 
How can achieve the same effect with Laravel Rest API  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To eager load the relation do.

```
Container::with('shop.images');
```

For what i know about `parent::toArray()` should include the images in the `ShopResource`, if not fill out the resource similar as done with the `ContainerResource`.

```
class Shop extends JsonResource
{

    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            ...
            'images' => ImageResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('images')),
        ];
    }
}
```

To eager load multiple relations, using the with method, it can also take an array.

```
Container::with(['shop.images', 'shop.employees',]);
```

Comment: thanks that helped me, though one thing comes to my mind. What if there was another table with foreign key to Shop model, eg employees and we would want to include them inside the Container as well . Container::with('shop.images')::with('shop.employees'); ?